# Xcode .gitignore files within directories

Tags: ios, xcode, gitignore

I am looking to `.gitignore` my plist file found within a subdirectory within my project. When I ignore individual files at the root level where `.gitignore` is located I have no problems with the exclusion, but when I try to exclude files within the a subdirectory I can't seem set up the proper way to exclude this and my file still appears. I think what is throwing me off the most is the way that my Xcode projects appear in my finder compared to my Xcode program. In Xcode, my `.plist` appears within a `Supporting Files` folder. Once would assume that this would mean my gitignore request would be `/app-name/Supporting Files/Info.plist`, but in the finder, there is no `Supporting Files` folder, just `Info.plist`.

Any advice as to what I should do?

[image: Xcode]

[image: Folders]

Should my .gitignore look like:

`facebook-login-template/Info.plist`

or

`/facebook-login-template/Supporting Files/Info.plist`

or should it be something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
*Info.plist
```

If you only want to avoid the one inside "facebook-login-template", it should work with

```
facebook-login-template/Info.plist
```

but remember you have to reset the file on git if you've already tracked it.